# NextAuth.JS auto redirecting when there is no active session

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, next-auth

TLDR: How do I disable the auto-redirection feature on NextAuth.JS for Credentials JWT authorization?

Using NextJS 13 /app directory with NextAuth.JS. I have scoured the NextAuth docs and SO and can't seem to find an answer. Currently, whenever I access a route without the JWT on local storage, it redirects to the '/api/signin' default page (which I later updated to be custom page) to login. My auth works just fine, if I sign in I am awarded a token and can navigate freely. The problem here is I can't create a route which allows for new users. Even the default or custom newUser option doesn't seem to work. Attempting to access any other page without a token is impossible.

Below are my authentication options at the moment:

```js
type User = {
    id: number,
    name: string
}

const credProvider = CredentialsProvider({
    id: "credentials",
    name: "Credentials",
    type: "credentials",
    credentials: {
        email:{ label: "email", type:"text" },
        password:{ label: "Password", type:"password"}
    },
    async authorize(credentials, req){
        if(credentials === undefined ){
            return null
        }

        await dbConnect();
        const potentialUser = await UserModel.findOne({ email : credentials.email})

        // TODO encrypt
        if(potentialUser && credentials.password === potentialUser.password){
            return potentialUser;
        }else{
            return null
        }
    }
})

export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        credProvider
    ],
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt'
    },
    pages:{
        signIn: '/auth/credentials-signin',
        newUser: '/auth/credentials-signup'
    }

}
```

Is it time to submit an issue to the NextAuth team? It seems like they haven't fully finished integrating with the new app directory yet because I am noticing some holes in their docs. Also, their `pages` option forces you to write files back into the pages directory which itself is something I would like to avoid if I can control the auto redirects.

Thanks for you help and let me know if I haven't included enough info.

Here is what I have tried:

- I tried changing the `authorize()` function to return a 'guest' session instead of `null` which can then be checked at each endpoint and handled accordingly, but this seems idiosyncratic and incorrect.
- I read all the docs searching for an option controlling redirects, but all I seem to find is others which have the opposite problem.
- I tried rewriting the `redirect()` callback to not redirect to the signIn page but this results in an infinite loop.

Comment: Not sure if this will help you, I just did something similar and I haven't that problem.
I'm using a middleware file to protect some routes and not all of them
(protect all routes inside of dashboard)
export const config = { matcher: ["/", "/dashboard/:path*"] };

Comment: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#middleware